# matplotlib plotting with python in xcode

Tags: python, xcode, matplotlib

I am trying to run python in XCode.  The following simple plotting routine,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
pyplot.plot((0,1),(1,2))
pyplot.show()
```

returns no errors.  XCode seems pretty happy with what it accomplishes when I hit the run button.  But I get no plot window whatsoever, as far as I can tell.  Is it hiding somewhere or what?  How do I get to see it?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand, but XCode is a language environment, not a platform to run the code. Assuming you've installed python, try saving your file, go to the terminal, type `python` and then `execfile("name.py")`. You should see the plot.

Comment: That I can do.  But I was hoping the XCode IDE would let me see the plot window.  Many IDEs have this capability.  If XCode does not, it won't be very useful for me.

Answer (score 1):

xcode will allow you to see plots if you move your code into an interactive notebook.

- create a new file with the `.ipynb` file extension
- copy your code into that file

You should be able not only to see the plots but also any other output your code is trying to send to the UI.

[image]